# How to separate input/output from pipe socket server in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have below source code about socket server/client in nodejs.

```
const net = require('net');

net.createServer((socket)=>{
  socket.pipe(socket);
  socket.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log('receive data ', data.toString());
    socket.write('this is server')

  });
}).listen(3000);

console.log("Chat server running at port 5000\n");

let client = new net.Socket();
client.setEncoding('utf8');
client.connect(3000, '127.0.0.1', function() {
    console.log('Connected');
    client.write('Hello, server! Love, Client.');
});

client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Received: ' + data);
});
```

when I run above code, the server will send the data(which is from the client) back to the client. I know this is cased by `socket.pipe(socket);`. I want to keep that code and am looking for a way to separate the input/output data in client side like below:

```
client.on('data', function(data) {
    if( the data is sent from client ){
        ...
    } else {
        //this is the data generated from server
    }
});
```

Does anyone know how to do that in nodejs client side?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can separate out the data from client and server, depending upon what messages you emit or what you listen, from that you can distinguish between client and server.

The message you emit from server are the message, you received on the client side if client is listening to that messages, the message you emit by client are the message received on server if server is listening to the messages.

Below is the code for a socket.io

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.send('<h1>SocketChat Server</h1>');
        });


http.listen(3000, function(){
            console.log('Listening on *:3000');
            });


io.on('connection', function(clientSocket){
   /* Here server is listening to client 'connectUser' message so here   data is sent from client*/
  clientSocket.on('connectUser', function(clientNickname, groupName) {
                      var message = "User " + clientNickname + " was connected." + clientSocket;

                          console.log(message);
 clientSocket.emit('userConnected');
});
});
```

/* Here server is emitting message('userConnected') that will be received by client. */

From above you can see that how to distinguish the client and server messages.

Comment: the problem I have is on the net.socket which means it uses `data` as the message. I can't change that message name.